# Displaying duplicate options values in a select with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, duplicates, html-select

Using the form helper in CakePHP 1.3, I'm trying to display a list (drop-down list) which contains several duplicated value fields (in `<option>` tag of course), but Cake does not seem to want to let me do it, and outputs only the first occurrence of each value.

For instance, here's the 'options' array of the $form->input:

```
array(
    0 => 'description 0',
    0 => 'description 1',
    0 => 'description 2',
    1 => 'description 3'
);
```

Which will output something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">description 0</option>
    <option value="1">description 3</option>
</select>
```

And I'm looking for this result:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">description 0</option>
    <option value="0">description 1</option>
    <option value="0">description 2</option>
    <option value="1">description 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as feared the problem was deeper than I first thought , and it was caused by PHP which does not (obviously) allow duplicate keys.

So here's my solution (if anyone's interested in):

1. Create a **new helper** extending the FormHelper
2. **Copy** the original function `__selectOptions()` from the form helper into your new helper
3. Just change this line: 
   `foreach ($elements as $name => $title) {`
    **by :**
   `foreach ($elements as $title => $name) {`
4. **Done!**

It's not the best solution as if you want to update your cakephp to the latest version after doing that, you have to copy/paste the function again, and do the same trick.

**How to use it:**

1. Declare your `options` array the other way around : `array('description' => 'key);`
2. In your view, instead of doing `$form->input`, just do `$yourhelper->input`

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you cannot use the same key twice in an array in PHP.

But as stated on this [article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/) cake knows how to make multiple keys with the same value in 2.x:

```
$options = array(
    ...
    array('name' => 'United states', 'value' => 'USA'),
    array('name' => 'USA', 'value' => 'USA'),
 );

 $html = $this->Form->select('field', $options);
```

resulting in

```
<option value="USA">United states</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
```

As you can see, you got your value here twice (or more of course) now.

See the documentation of the form helper class itself (cake2.x).
Not sure if 1.3 does already support it, though.

If you upgrade, you will be able to leverage all of cake's newest magic.